# Avoiding "Other element would receive the click" with elementToBeClickable

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, clickable, browser-automation

I have this method using implicit wait pre configured to return me some `WebElement`:

```
private WebElement findElement(By locator) {
    WebElement element = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfTries && element == null; i++)
        try {
            waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
            element = driver.findElement(locator);
        } catch (TimeoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(specificStringAboutTimeOutAndNoSuchEl);
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            Throwable cause = null;
            Throwable result = e;
            while (null != (cause = result.getCause()) && (result != cause))
                result = cause;
            System.out.println(specificStringAboutException);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    return element;
}
```

And this to wait to some other element vanish, like spinners and loading screens:

```
private void waitsElementToVanish(By locator, String previousOp) {
        List<Class<? extends Throwable>> ignorableExceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        ignorableExceptions.add(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        ignorableExceptions.add(NoSuchElementException.class);
        try {
            if (driver.findElements(locator).size() > 0)
                System.out.println(locator.toString() + " exists");
            waiter.ignoreAll(ignorableExceptions).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
            waiter.ignoreAll(ignorableExceptions).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("timeout waiting " + locator.toString() + " to vanish");
            System.out.println(previousOp);
        }
    }
```

And I use them like this:

```
waitsElementToVanish(By.className("spinnerLoading"), "someString");
findElement(By.xpath(otherElement)).click();
```

And I get this error at `.click()`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="menuContent ellipsis flex flexGrow">...</div> is not clickable at point (136, 240). Other element would receive the click: <div class="spinnerLoading">...</div>
```

[This](https://uat-xgracco.enforcegroup.com.br/login) is the website I'm using and this application is purely educational. This is [the entire code](https://github.com/gabriel119435/SeleniumTests).

Should I wrap `Selenium` `click` method into some WebDriverException like:

1. Tries to click, if WebDriverException is thrown with `spinnerClass` on it, goes to `waitsElementToVanish` and then tries again
2. If number of tries goes beyond limit, then it throws some `ReallyMessedUpExceptionDoSomething!` exception.

My question is: I want to avoid `Thread.sleep()` at all costs. I want optimize test time waiting only for what it's coming, not for some pre fixed period without checking anything on page. The 'good practice actions' are really wrap click on many tries? How I can assure I'm avoiding spinner even when the line before tried that too? And I don't see any problem wrapping click on a loop to try again and again with a limit. But, actually, what is the best solution here?